# .NET Google Wallet API Integration (Google.Apis.Walletobjects.v1)

Tags: .net, google-pay

I have an urge to generate Loyalty Cards on Google Wallet. (Web API)
They provided examples and documentation, but there is one thing that is missing and I have no idea how to I get access to it.

```
Google.Apis.Walletobjects.v1
```

This is the namespace I'm looking for, but there is no Nuget Package or Github library project that relates to this.
Google themselves did not provide it (at least publicaly)

I tried to find different approaches to do the integration but it seems it's the one easiest way..

Is there anyone who implemented Loyalty Cards and can tell me where do I get this resource?

Comment: I believe you can download the source here: https://developers.google.com/wallet/generic/resources/libraries#c

Comment: @JonSkeet I did, and that's the problem that source code does not contain anything related to Google.Apis.Walletobjects

Comment: It really does - the [zip file](https://developers.google.com/static/wallet/downloads/google-walletobjects-v1-rev_20221109-csharp.zip) contains Google.Apis.Walletobjects.cs which contains everything you need.

Comment: Out of interest, any idea why is this not published to nuget? There is a .nuspec file in the zip already!

Comment: @L4ur15 able to get any solution so far? If yes, I need to integrate the service to generate google generic pass. Please help me on it